# Error with copy and paste function on script

Tags: excel, vba

My script looks up the highest values in `dailySht` and pastes the values into a separate sheet `recordSht`, which usually works fine, but I sometimes get the error `Object variable or With block variable not set`. Below is the part of the code that returns the error.

```
Sub DailyBH()
    Dim dailySht As Worksheet 'worksheet storing latest store activity
    Dim recordSht As Worksheet 'worksheet to store the highest period of each day
    Dim lColDaily As Integer ' Last column of data in the store activity sheet
    Dim lCol As Integer ' Last column of data in the record sheet
    Dim maxCustomerRng2 As Range ' Cell containing the highest number of customers
    Dim maxCustomerCnt As Double ' value of highest customer count

    Set dailySht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("hourly KPI")
    Set recordSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("@BH KPI")
    With recordSht
        lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    End With

    With dailySht
        lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        maxCustomerCnt = Round(Application.Max(.Range(.Cells(58, 1), .Cells(58, lColDaily))), 2)
        Set maxCustomerRng2 = .Range(.Cells(58, 1), .Cells(58, lColDaily)).Find(What:=maxCustomerCnt, LookIn:=xlValues)

        .Cells(4, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
        recordSht.Cells(4, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        recordSht.Cells(4, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

        .Cells(22, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
        recordSht.Cells(22, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        recordSht.Cells(22, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

        .Cells(40, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
        recordSht.Cells(40, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        recordSht.Cells(40, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

        .Cells(49, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
        recordSht.Cells(49, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        recordSht.Cells(49, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats

        .Cells(58, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy
        recordSht.Cells(58, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        recordSht.Cells(58, lCol + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
    End With

    Set maxCustomerRng = Nothing
    Set dailySht = Nothing
    Set recordSht = Nothing
End Sub
```

Can someone please help me figure out that the problem is, as the code works (copies and pastes the correct values) on some cells and not others.

Comment: Can you tell us in which line the error occurs please?

Comment: You need to test `maxCustomerRng2` after the `.Find` call to make sure you actually found something. It returns `Nothing` if there isn't a match.

Comment: You're also rounding `maxCustomerCnt` before you search for it in the same range. If it *does* round, you aren't going to find it in the same range because the range contains...the unrounded values.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ the error occurs on all lines wiith .Copy, starting from .Cells(4, maxCustomerRng2.Column).Copy

Comment: @Comintern removing the round function has fixed most of the errors, but not all of them. Also the maxCustomerRng2 returns Nothing but I can't figure out whats causing it as I've removed the round function.

Comment: It's possible that there are some floating point issues. With that small a range, I'd suggest just writing your own function for finding the row instead of fighting with `Find`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use `Match` instead of `Find` and use the result of `Max` directly without converting it into `Double` to avoid floating point inaccuracies.

```
With dailySht
    lColDaily = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Dim SearchRange As Range
    Set SearchRange = .Range(.Cells(58, 1), .Cells(58, lColDaily))

    Dim MaxCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next 'next line throws error if nothing matched
    MaxCol = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(SearchRange), SearchRange, 0)
    On Error GoTo 0 're-enable error reporting !!!

    If MaxCol = 0 Then
        'nothing was found
        Exit Sub
    End If

    .Cells(4, MaxCol).Copy
    'your stuff here
```